# How to center text over an image while keeping it below fixed nav bar in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed nav bar with transparency on top of my page

```
header {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 text-align: center; }
```

which I'd like to go in front of* my header image spanning across the entire width of the page.

```
#bgimg {
 background-image: url(bannerimg.jpg);
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1900px;
 height: 800px;
 background-position: center;
 margin: 0 auto; }
```

Here's my html

```
<section>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About us</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Blogs</li>
            <li>Partners</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
            <li>Career</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
    <div id="bgimg">
        <h1>Sample Text<br/>Sample Text</h1>
        <p>A paragraph</p>
    </div>
</header>
```

The problem is, other answers I've found suggest setting the image-containing div's positioning to relative and the text to absolute, but when I try that, the image overlaps the navigation bar. How do I keep it below it and still center the text both horizontally and vertically? I'm fairly new to html and css so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a JS Fiddle or other demo so we can see what you mean more clearly?

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xcunsdz/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2xcunsdz/2/ here's a more detailed one. I want to achieve something similar to this in terms of the text over the image  http://cdn.sixrevisions.com/0444-01_fixed-navigation-bar/fixed-navigation-bar.html but with a transparent fixed nav bar over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this was exactly what you were looking for, but here is a solution that uses z-order and display: table.
https://jsfiddle.net/2xcunsdz/3/
So, the CSS comes out like this:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

header {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 text-align: center;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: 2;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 30px 0px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;}

#bgimg {
 display: table;
 position: relative;
 background-image: url(https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1424746219973-8fe3bd07d8e3?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=725&q=75&w=1050);
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1900px;
 height: 800px;
 background-position: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}


#textDiv {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also note that your HTML was a little out of order. The  and  tags need to be swapped around. I also wrapped the text that displays on top of the image in a div, to make things easier.

Comment: This minus the `padding-top: 50px` was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much, I need to look into `display: table` and `z-index` more. And yes, I hadn't noticed the html was a bit off. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you also happen to know how I can place a border around the text? If I place it around the div it covers the whole area, and it seems impractical to place it on the top and the sides of the heading and on the bottom and sides of the paragraph so that they join up.

Comment: If you know the width of your text, you could wrap them it in a div with a set width and margin set to 0 auto. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2xcunsdz/4/

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap method is to use a top padding to move the contents of the  the same height as the fixed navigation bar.

> Body padding required
>   The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the . Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Comment: Yeah this makes sense if I don't want the image to be partially visible behind the nav bar. I made a mistake in my initial post, I wanted the nav bar to go _on top of_ the image.